# "Canonical" norm on a real finite-dimensional unital associative division algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, quaternions, division-algebras, octonions

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the category of unital *associative* finite-dimensional *division* $\mathbb{R}$-algebras. (As a full subcategory of that of unital $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.)

For $A\in \mathcal{C}$ of real dimension $0<d<\infty$,
let us define the function
$$
\begin{matrix}
f_A &:&A & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \\
&& a & \mapsto & 
 \bigl| \mathrm{det}\bigl( (x \mapsto ax)\in \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{R}\textrm{-Mod}}(A) \bigr)  \bigr|^{1/d}
\end{matrix}
$$
sending $a \in A$ to the $1/d$ power of the absolute value of the determinant of the left-$a$-multiplication self-map on $A$, viewed as an $\mathbb{R}$-linear self-map (so computed using an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $A$).

Furthermore, $f_A$ is sort of "iso-natural" in that it's preserved under pre-composition by isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$; i.e. if $\psi : A' \xrightarrow{\simeq} A$ is a given isomorphism between objects in $\mathcal{C}$, then $f_A \circ \psi = f_{A'}$.

Some other immediate properties of $f_A$:

- It is nonnegative-valued, and $f_A(a) = 0$ implies $a=0$ for $a\in A$. (The 2nd part uses that $A$ is a division alg.)
- It satisfies $f_A(ta) = |t|f_A(a)$ for $a \in A, t \in \mathbb{R}$.

(Note these are the first two requirements for a *norm*; the remaining one is the triangle inequality.)

---

Next, by direct computation, we observe:

> For $A \in \{ \mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C} , \mathbb{H}\}$ (using some fixed standard constructions for these), it seems the function $f$ does give a **norm** which actually agrees with the one induced by the ($\mathbb{R}$-bilinear) inner product having the following as orthonormal $\mathbb{R}$-bases:
>
> - $\{ 1\}$ for $\mathbb{R}$,
> - $\{ 1,i \}$ for $\mathbb{C}$,
> - $\{ 1,i,j,k \}$ for $\mathbb{H}$.

Thus:

> If we take it as already known that $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}$ exhausts all the isomorphism classes of $\mathcal{C}$ (which is a well-known result),
> then by the above (including "iso-naturality" of $f_A$ mentioned above), we can conclude $f_A$ is always a norm;
>
> in particular $f_A$ always satisfies the triangle inequality.

---

My first question (assuming my reasoning above is sound)
is:

> 1. Is there a way to see more directly that $f_A$ satisfies the triangle inequality, without needing to know beforehand that any $A \in \mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to one of $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}$?

Next:

If we relax the "associative" condition for $A \in \mathcal{C}$ to "alternative", then it is known that the isomorphism classes of $\mathcal{C}$ are then $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},\mathbb{O}$.
(Cf. Proposition 3.1 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/normed+division+algebra; although that article is about normed division algebras, Prop 3.1 focuses on alternative div algebras but without a choice of norm.)

So my second question is:

> 2. Is $f_{\mathbb{O}}$ also a norm, on the octonion space $\mathbb{O}$? For example, maybe it is the norm induced by the inner product having as orthonormal basis $e_0,e_1,\ldots,e_7$, using the notation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion.

(I tried working through the computation for $\mathbb{O}$ but I found it got somewhat messy and I couldn't figure out how to make it more tractable.)

---

Edit: added the 2nd question about alternative division algebras, and the octonions $\mathbb{O}$.

Comment: An observation: it is not true for division algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$ (for instance, over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ you would get $f_A(a+b\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{|a^2-2b^2|}$ and this fails the triangle inequality on $-1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}$).  So any proof would have to use *something* about how division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are restricted and not just be a purely formal calculation.

Comment: Also not true for non-division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ (if $A=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, then left-multiplication gives purely diagonal matrices, so $f_A(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$…but $\sqrt{(1+1)(1+2)}\nleq\sqrt{1\cdot1}+\sqrt{1\cdot2}$).